# how to update a SQQLite database with particular row?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

while updating in database, I'm not getting the id of particular row
here is my code for update Note in database

```
public int updateNote(int id, String tittle, String content , String update_at)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(Note.COLUMN_TITTLE,tittle);
        values.put(Note.COLUMN_CONTENT,content);
        values.put(Note.COLUMN_TITTLE,update_at);
        return db.update(Note.TABLE_NAME,values,Note.COLUMN_ID+"="+id,null);

    }
```

Please help me.

Comment: it will work if you give this method the ID of the row

Comment: check id in Log to confirm

Comment: are you using any list view and getter setter for each datas add in db

Comment: @RevathiManoharan yes i m using getter and setter in a list view...

Comment: @MustafaShaikh let you check my answer .i hope its usefull to you

Answer (score 2):

`update` returns the number of rows affected and not the id of the row.  
In your case if successful it would return 1.  
About the id you need you already have it.

Answer (score 0):

As mTak outlined, the `update` method returns the number of rows affected. You can also see that in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#update(java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])).

If you want your method to return the ID of the row you updated, then return the `id` that you pass in, since that's how you select the row to update in the first place:

```
public int updateNote(int id, String tittle, String content , String update_at) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(Note.COLUMN_TITTLE,tittle);
    values.put(Note.COLUMN_CONTENT,content);
    values.put(Note.COLUMN_TITTLE,update_at);
    db.update(Note.TABLE_NAME,values,Note.COLUMN_ID+"="+id,null);

    return id;
}
```

Comment: its not updating in database bro i try it and i m using getter and setter. while updating its showing in list view but after re-opening the app it gone from the list view...

Answer (score 0):

In your Activity Class:

```
 //*Note is your setterClass  
 //*notesList is your ArrayList or list
 //*position refers your current list position
 //*setNote is a method in Note Class

 private void updateNote(String note, int position) {
        Note n = notesList.get(position);
        // updating note text
        n.setNote(note);

        // updating note in db
        db.updateNote(n);

        // refreshing the list
        notesList.set(position, n);
        mAdapter.notifyItemChanged(position);
    }
```

In your database class try below code:

```
 public int updateNote(Note note) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(Note.COLUMN_NOTE, note.getNote());

        // updating row
        return db.update(Note.TABLE_NAME, values, Note.COLUMN_ID + " = ?",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(note.getId())});
    }
```

here i am trying to update single string.i hope this is workig to you.Let me know is this working or not.